# Why PHPMailer/Google SMTP Server is so slow

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I am trying to create a simple contact form using PHPMailer and here is what i got so far:

**contact.php:**

```
<?php

require 'includes/config.php';
require 'includes/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

function sanitize($text) {
    $text = trim($text);

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $text = stripslashes($text);
    }

    $text = strip_tags($text);

    return $text;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $entries  = array();
    $response = array();

    // Escape and extract all the post values
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $entries[$key] = sanitize($value);
    }


    $name         = $entries['cf_name'];
    $email        = $entries['cf_email'];
    $message      = $entries['cf_message'];
    $subject      = 'Contact form';
    $replySubject = 'Contact form';
    $mailBody     = '<b>Email message</b>';


    // Check is an AJAX request
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

        // Create a new PHPMailer instance
        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        // Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
        $mail->isSMTP();
        // Set the hostname of the mail server
        $mail->Host       = MAIL_HOST;
        // Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS
        $mail->Port       = MAIL_PORT;
        // Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        // Whether to use SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        // Username to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = MAIL_USER;
        // Password to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Password   = MAIL_PASS;


        // Set who the message is to be sent from
        $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
        // Set an alternative reply-to address
        $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
        // Set who the message is to be sent to
        $mail->addAddress(MAIL_ADDR);
        // Set the subject line
        $mail->Subject = 'Formularz kontaktowy';

        // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        // HTML version
        $mail->Body    = $mailBody;
        // Convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
        $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($mailBody);

        // send the message
        if ($mail->send()) {
            $response['result'] = 1;
        } else {
            $response['result'] = 0;
            $response['error'] = $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }

        echo json_encode($response);

    } else {
        header('Location: ' . BASE_URL);
        exit();
    }

} else {
    header('Location: ' . BASE_URL);
    exit();
}
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
    define('BASE_URL', 'http://example.com');
    define('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com');
    define('MAIL_PORT', 587);
    define('MAIL_USER', 'mygmailemail@gmail.com');
    define('MAIL_PASS', 'mygmailpassword');
    define('MAIL_ADDR', 'example@email.com');
```

**Client-Side:**

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

    var t1 = window.performance.now();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: this.action,
        data: formData
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        console.log('DONE', response);

        var t2 = window.performance.now();

        console.log('time', (t2 - t1) / 1000);
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
        console.log('FAIL', response);
    });

});
```

I am testing this code locally with EasyPHP Server. As you can see above i log time inside ajax done callback and the average time to send an email is 3-5 seconds which i found ridiculously slow. I am not PHP developer so I have no idea why is it so slow. Is it EasyPHP fault or something else I did wrong? Can you please tell how can I improve this code to send out emails faster?

Comment: How about switching the logic and adding timestamp tracking on the PHP end to see what parts of the PHP are taking too long to respond? It's likely the initial connection to the SMTP server....

Comment: you have http(ajax)->server->smtp(gmail). first you have to figure out which stage is the slow one. And note that your location headers are pointless. you're doing an ajax request. there's nothing to redirect.

Comment: On the other hand, if it is a simple contact form, you are not to worry about waiting some seconds for receiving the email, and you want to send the client to thanks page as soon as possible, you can save the submitted data in the DB, and create a service that checks if there is any new submitted contact form, and sends all pending emails in a batch (using BCC for example).

Comment: SMTP is not a real-time protocol - there are sections of it that include 10-minute timeouts! Sending during a page refresh is really not a good way to go, though many still do it. If you want it to be fast, run a local mail server to offload the task and send asynchronously, or hand off to your own sending process.